# displaying values in ng- repeat by looping through array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have written a code to pass values from input and pushing it into an array.Then I am trying to display the values of the list in a table by using ng- repeat.But I am not able to display the values in the array.I am not able to display my code in dispList.

Please let me know how to display the array objects in dispList.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: no code is there..

Answer (score 0):

As I am lacking your code snippet I thought I would just create some add  and list logic:

//javascript

```
$scope.list = [];
$scope.addItem = function( item ) {
  $scope.list.push( { name : item.name, price : item.price } )
}
```

// view

```
<div>
 <input ng-model="item.name" placeholder="name"></input>
 <input ng-model="item.price" placeholder="price"></input>
 <button ng-click="addItem( item )" >Add</button>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="it in list">
  {{ it.name }} {{ it.price }}
</div>
```